# How to differentiate between an SQL user and a Windows Domain user?

Tags: sql-server, go

I am creating a connection to an SQL Server DB.

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"

    _ "github.com/denisenkom/go-mssqldb"
)

func main() {

    host := "10.50.30.20"
    user := "admin"  //"UDA\\admin"   
    pwd := "password"
    port := 1433
    defaultDBName := "master"
    defaultDriverName := "mssql"
    testConnectionQuery := "SELECT name FROM users WHERE age=42;"

    connString := fmt.Sprintf("server=%v;user id=%v;password=%v;port=%v;database=%v;",
        host, user, pwd, port, defaultDBName)
    conn, err := sql.Open(defaultDriverName, connString)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Failed to open sql server connection, err: %v", err)

    }
    defer conn.Close()
    err = conn.Ping()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Failed to connect to server connection, err: %v", err)
    }
    _, queryErr := conn.Query(testConnectionQuery)
    if queryErr != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error: %v", queryErr)
    }

}
```

This works fine.

My problem is that the user can be SQL user or a Domain user.
How can I differentiate between the two? because right now both of them are able to connect.

I want to let SQL user connect and bar the Domain user from connecting.

P.S I don't want to disable Domain User, I just don't want the Domain user to connect via this code.

P.P.S I am able to connect to the DB with a username that is a WINDOWS_LOGIN type. I was calling that a Domain user. Apologies if that is not the right term. What I was referring to was `<DomainName>\<UserName> - Could be an MSA or AD user account.`

Comment: The connection strings for a Windows User and a SQL Authentication User are different. Ss you're using a User and Password in the Connection String then the authentication method can only use SQL Authentication; Windows Authentication doesn't use either. Trying to connect as a Windows User with a Username and Password will fail as it will try to authenticate against a non-existent SQL User.

Comment: Note, as well, that you cannot disable Windows Authentication on SQL Server. SQL Server only has 2 authentication modes; Windows Authentication or Mixed Authentication. In both Windows Credentials are enabled. Though, if you don't want a specific Windows User to be able to authenticate with a trusted connection, just ensure you don't create the user, or groups they belong to, a `LOGIN` on the instance.

Comment: @Larnu I am able to connect to the DB with a username that is a WINDOWS_LOGIN type. I was calling that a Domain user. Apologies if that is not the right term. What I was refering to was `<DomainName>\<UserName> - Could be an MSA or AD user account.`

Comment: *" I just don't want the Domain user to connect via this code"* Again, from my original comment "The connection strings for a Windows User and a SQL Authentication User are different. If you're using a User and Password in the Connection String then the authentication method can only use SQL Authentication" The above connection string **cannot** use Windows Authentication.